# Positioning a UIPageControl on a UIViewController with respect to the position of a UIView on it's subViewController.

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

So I've got a problem with layout and constraints.

I'm using the app coda tutorial for UIPageViewControllers at http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/ but I've made some small changes.

I have added a content view controller as subview to my main view controller. It matches the height and width of its superview. On this subview I have laid out a UIImageView and a UISegmentedControl (see screenshot). I have also added some constraints to this view controller, which ties the UIImageView to the top,right and left of its container, also the segmented control is centred on the image view and added constraints to the uiimageview above and the container bottom below. The effect of this is that the view controller maintains its appearance on different device sizes.
[image]
However, I need to position a UIPageControl (page indicator) at the bottom of the UIImageView but I do not want to place it on the subview because then it would turn with the pages of the UIPageViewController - so I position it on the SuperView (see screenshot). I use;

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pageControl];
```

to bring my page control always to the front of the view hierarchy. The final result should look like the below screenshot,

[image]

however the relative location of the page indicator on the superview changes for different devices.

My question is how can I add constraints to this page indicator on it's own viewController so that when the page indicator is positioned on the superview it always appears at the bottom of the UIImageview which is positioned on the subview no matter what device it is run on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found a simple answer....

just add a new UIImageView to the SuperView and set similar constraints so that it obeys the same scaling laws as the UIImageView in the subview. Then use layout constraints to anchor the page indicator to the bottom of the new UIIMageView.

see screenshot.

[image]